# Программная загрузка компонентов в winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

У меня на winforms форме есть несколько TabControl с несколькими вкладками. Проблема в том, что элементы на них не прогружаются, пока ты сам не откроешь эту вкладку. Можно ли как то при запуске программы прогрузить все ее компоненты?

Comment: они и не должны прогружаться, пока вкладка не активна. В чем проблема-то, что они не прогружаются? Там какие-то данные должны прогрузиться из вне? Тогда пора переходить к нормальной архитектуре и данные прогружать в модельных классах, а контролы просто биндить на модель.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В окне конструктора вашей формы выберите ваш TabControl, и окне Свойств выберите TapPages (Коллекция) , должна открыться форма где вы можете редактировать.

[image: редактор коллекции]

Comment: А какие параметры там нужно отредактировать, чтобы решить мою проблему?

Comment: @PracticeMakesPerfect выложите ваш пример, и пример данных которые вы хотите "подгрузить".